# Create a new iteration using TFS REST API

Tags: tfs, iteration, azure-devops, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

I think there is a problem with the new [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/overview). Let me explain :

Here is an example of a **classification node**, which is basically an  "inactive" iteration (not shown with the other sprint in TFS) :

```
{
  "id": 126391,
  "name": "Web",
  "structureType": "area",
  "hasChildren": false,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Areas/Web"
    },
    "parent": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Areas"
    }
  },
  "url": "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Areas/Web"
}
```

Pay attention to the "id" field. It's not a **TFS GUID**, it's a basic id.

Now, here is what you need to send to the API to append your classification node to a team, which is the way to active your classification node as an **iteration** :

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/TeamSettings/Iterations?api-version={version}

"{\"id\":\"a589a806-bf11-4d4f-a031-c19813331553\"}"
```

This is the problem ! You need the **GUID** of your classification node to append it to a team but there is no way to retrieve it...

Can someone explain me how is it possible ?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 6/24/2016**
Here's what I retrieve when I'm asking for all the classification nodes :

```
https://{...}/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/iterations?$depth=2
```

[Classification nodes tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzysA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the GUID of the iterations/areas via Rest API. Can you retry and provide your steps if you can still see the issue?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but what I need is the classification node GUID, not the iteration GUID.

Comment: @Blockost Classification node has two type: iteration and area. And the example you provide is getting the information for an "area" node. The sample response in the Rest API document page does not include the GUID, but it does exist in the response when I get it at my side.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see the identifier field... See my update on the original post.

Comment: @Blockost Which type of classification node are you getting? Iteration or Area?

Comment: I'm retrieving Iterations. I've posted a screenshot of my postman's response. But, it's the same for areas. I don't have the 'identifier' field...

Comment: @Blockost Get a team's iterations does not include this information. You need to get one iteration according to this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes#get-an-iteration

Comment: Here's my request : "{...}/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/iterations/Release 1/Sprint 1?api-version=1.0". As you advise me, I'm retrieving only one iteration. But, still, the 'identifier' field is not present....

Comment: @Blockost What is the "structureType" in the response message?

Comment: @Blockost Are you using Visual Studio Team Services? Or On-premise TFS server?

Comment: I'm using _On-premise TFS server_. Is that deprecated ?

Comment: @Blockost Which version are you using? I just tried with TFS2015 Update3 RC and can get it.

Comment: Apparently, not this one... But it's an RC version, I can't use it in production anyway... Is there a stable version allowing to retrieve the identifier field ?

Answer (score -1):

Look at the published API document below, I think its what you need.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version={version}[&stateFilter{string}&$top={integer}&skip={integer}]
```

Example
https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0

```
   {
  "count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1",
      "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
      "description": "Team Foundation Version Control projects.",
      "url": "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1",
      "state": "wellFormed"
    },
    {
      "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
      "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
      "description": "Git projects",
      "url": "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
      "state": "wellFormed"
    },
    {
      "id": "281f9a5b-af0d-49b4-a1df-fe6f5e5f84d0",
      "name": "TestGit",
      "url": "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/281f9a5b-af0d-49b4-a1df-fe6f5e5f84d0",
      "state": "wellFormed"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The Ids returned from this are the PROJECT GUIDs, not the ones in question.

Comment: Its calling the visual studio online API. So wouldn't be returned the id, from the API?

Comment: As well he want the team id and the document gives him the api call for the team detail.

Comment: Notice the guids in the _links\self\href (this is the project guid already there). You are correct about needing the team guid but that is not present here either, you can use the project guid to get it from the team api. As I understand it the question is how to get the classification node guid id. 

Team API: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams

OP should look at this SO post, I think it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550144/visual-studio-rest-api-iteration-and-area-ids

I think it will let you query with the Iteration NAME.