# Converting GUID Iteration id to iteration id in TFS

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am currently using the TFS Rest API in PowerShell to get the iteration id, start date and finish date for each current iteration for each team. When I view the iteration id I get the GUID. Is there any way to convert the GUID to the iteration id that is shown in TFS?

https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/TeamSettings/Iterations?[$timeframe=current&]api-version={version}

When I use the query above I get a GUID like below:
9fdb24a1-ebfb-47af-a50b-0521011f17cd

I want to convert to the integer Iteration ID (ex. 147) that is in the TFS.

Here is the iterationID used in the work item part of TFS (from the process editor):

[image: System.IterationID]

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.0-preview.1

Comment: What are you trying to do with the ID

Comment: I am going to use the iteration id to query through to get remaining work of all team members to find their committed capacity for the iteration. Using [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore] to create query.

Comment: What's the iteration id shown in your TFS? Do you mean iteration name?

Comment: Could you add a related screenshot to show the iteration id in your case?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT When querying a workitem, the only documented data for iteration are System.IterationPath and System.IterationID - System.IterationID being an integer instead of a guid. I never understood either how we are supposed to match an iteration with it, when the only available api is using a guid as an id in the different versions of the api (either soap or webapi)

Comment: @AlexGlasnovich See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550144/visual-studio-rest-api-iteration-and-area-ids to use the iteration path instead of the id to match iteration between the two sides of the api.

Comment: @AlexGlasnovich - I'm running into the same issue, any luck?